# Show parent NavLink as active in React Router V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a multi-level navigation, where the first child is the `index` route (e.g. the `Company Details` item is the `index` route for `/companies`):

```
Home     Companies     

Company Details     Users
```

This is my routes setup:

```
<Routes>
  <Route index element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="companies" element={<Companies />}>
    <Route index element={<CompaniesList />} />
    <Route path=":companyId" element={<Company />}>
      <Route index element={<CompanyDetail />} />
      <Route path="users" element={<Users />}>
        <Route index element={<UserList />} />
        <Route path=":userId" element={<UserDetail />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

This essentially creates this route structure (note that `Details` and `Users` are siblings):

```
Companies:            /companies
  - Details:          /companies/:companyId
  - Users:            /companies/:companyId/users
      - User Details: /companies/:companyId/users/:userId
```

I'm using `<NavLink>` to set the active class for the current page in the navigation component:

```
<NavLink to="..." className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'is-active' : '')} />
```

If I navigate to the `Details` page, everything works as expected. That nav item and the parent `Companies` nav item are both active.

If I navigate to the `Users` page (`/companies/:companyId/users`), all three items (`Companies`, `Details`, and `Users`) are active. I don't want the `Details` link to be active.

If I add the `end` prop to the `<NavLink />` component (`<NavLink ... end />`), that fixes the `Details` link, but the `Companies` link is now not active. If I navigate to the `User Details` page, then *nothing* is active.

I've also tried using `useLocation()` to match the pathname, but this still matches on `Details` since `/companies/:companyId/users` includes `/companies/:companyId`:

```js
const location = useLocation();

const isParent = location.pathname.includes(pathname);
```

Is there a way to determine if a route is a true parent of the active route? In my case, `Details` should not be considered a parent of `Users`, but `Companies` should.

Answer (score 2):

Only add the `end` prop to the `NavLink` components you want to match when the path ends *exactly* with that target path.

Example:

```
<NavLink
  to="/companies" // <-- any "/companies/*
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "is-active" : "")}
>
  Companies List
</NavLink>
<NavLink
  end // <-- only when "/companies/:companyId"
  to="/companies/...."
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "is-active" : "")}
>
  ....
</NavLink>
<NavLink
  end // <-- only when "/companies/:companyId/users"
  to="/companies/..../users"
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "is-active" : "")}
>
  ....
</NavLink>
<NavLink
  end // <-- only when "/companies/:companyId/users/:userId"
  to="/companies/..../users/...."
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? "is-active" : "")}
>
  ....
</NavLink>
```

[image: Edit show-parent-navlink-as-active-in-react-router-v6]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This was helpful in sending me in the right direction. What I ended up with is using the `end` prop and manually adding the `is-active` class if there is a match in the pathname: `location.pathname.includes(pathname)`.